# Group and split records in postgres into several new column series

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have data of the form

```
-----------------------------|
6031566779420 | 25  | 163698 |
6031566779420 | 50  | 98862  |
6031566779420 | 75  | 70326  |
6031566779420 | 95  | 51156  |
6031566779420 | 100 | 43788  |
6036994077620 | 25  | 41002  |
6036994077620 | 50  | 21666  |
6036994077620 | 75  | 14604  |
6036994077620 | 95  | 11184  |
6036994077620 | 100 | 10506  |
------------------------------
```

and would like to create a dynamic number of new columns by treating each series of (25, 50, 75, 95, 100) and corresponding values as a new series. What I'm looking for as target output is,

```
--------------------------
| 25    | 163698 | 41002 |
| 50    | 98862  | 21666 |
| 75    | 70326  | 14604 |
| 95    | 51156  | 11184 |
| 100   | 43788  | 10506 |
--------------------------
```

I'm not sure what the name of the sql / postgres operation I want is called nor how to achieve it. In this case the data has 2 new columns but I'm trying to formulate a solution that has has many new columns as are groups of data in the output of the original query.

[Edit]

Thanks for the references to `array_agg`, that looks like it would be helpful! I should've mentioned this earlier but I'm using Redshift which reports this version of Postgres:

```
PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1007
```

and it does not seem to support this function yet.

```
ERROR:  function array_agg(numeric) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: function array_agg(numeric) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

Is crosstab the type of transformation I should be looking at? Or something else? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [`array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) here

```
select idx,array_agg(val) 
from t
group by idx
```

This will produce result like below:

```
idx array_agg      
--- -------------- 
25  {163698,41002} 
50  {98862,21666}  
75  {70326,14604}  
95  {11184,51156}  
100 {43788,10506}
```

As you can see the second column is an array of two values(column `idx`) that corresponding to column `idx`

The following select queries will give you result with two separate column

**`Method : 1`**

```
 SELECT idx
       ,col [1] col1 --First value in the array
       ,col [2] col2 --Second vlaue in the array
FROM (
    SELECT idx
        ,array_agg(val) col
    FROM t
    GROUP BY idx
    ) s
```

**`Method : 2`**

```
SELECT idx
    ,(array_agg(val)) [1] col1 --First value in the array
    ,(array_agg(val)) [2] col2 --Second vlaue in the array
FROM t
GROUP BY idx
```

**`Result:`**

```
idx col1   col2  
--- ------ ----- 
25  163698 41002 
50  98862  21666 
75  70326  14604 
95  11184  51156 
100 43788  10506
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_agg` function. Asuming, your columns are named `A`,`B`,`C`:

```
SELECT B, array_agg(C)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY B
```

Will get you output in array form. This is as close as you can get to variable columns in a simple query. If you really need variable columns, consider defining a [PL/pgSQL procedure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) to convert array into columns.